# laravel relationship can not find the data

Tags: php, laravel

model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ammu extends Model
{
    public function baccha(){

        return $this->hasOne('App\baccha');
    }
}
```

route

```
Route::get('/ammusbaccha',function(){
    return ammu::find(1)->baccha;
});
```

and it shows 
[this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6J8T.png)

Comment: Error's quite clear there: there is no column `ammu_id` in your table `bacchas`. Create one using migrations.

Comment: post your migration as well.
as the error suggest there is no amu_id in your table

Answer (score 0):

There's no entry with ammu_id 1 in your table

Answer (score 0):

The baccha table doesn't have the ammu_id foreign key.